# Display rows of a table depending on the user's role and another parameter, ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The app is developed in ASP.NET MVC4.

I have a table where a document name is specified, its type and  status.
The content is displayed fine. I want to display the rows of the table to the user depending on the role assigned  and the status of the document.

ViewBag.Statuses = new String[] { "text", "text2", "text3"}

```
  @grid.GetHtml(

            columns: grid.Columns(

                grid.Column(header: "Id", format: @<text><div>@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1)</div></text>),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "nom", header: "Nom"),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "type", header: "Type", format: (item) => ViewBag.Types[item.type]),
                        grid.Column(columnName: "status", header: "Status", format: (item) => ViewBag.Statuses[item.status])


                                                      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need specify user type in razor. That is the best place for your case. try something like:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
 columns: grid.Columns(
   @if (User.IsInRole("SystemAdministrator") ||User.IsInRole("Distributor"))
             { 
              grid.Column(header: "Id", format: @<text>
             }
           grid.Column(columnName: "type", header: "Type", format: (item) => ViewBag.Types[item.type]),
                            grid.Column(columnName: "status", header: "Status", format: (item) => ViewBag.Statuses[item.status])
```